# convert data in date format and aggregate date by month and to count frequency

Tags: r

I have a data frame that contains a date column that is in integer type.

```
df
date        values
11/25/18   a
11/30/18   b
12/4/18    a
12/5/18    b
12/5/18    a
12/6/18    b 
12/6/18    c
12/6/18    a
12/6/18    a
12/7/18    b
12/7/18    c
12/7/18    a
12/9/18    b
12/12/18   a
12/12/18   c
12/13/18   b 
1/9/19     a
1/9/19     c
1/9/19     b
1/10/19    d
1/10/19    d
1/10/19    d
1/10/19    a
1/11/19    c
1/11/19    d
2/1/19     a
2/10/19    a
2/13/19    b
3/14/19    d
3/17/19    c
5/4/19     d
5/5/19     c
5/6/19     d
5/31/19    a
```

I was trying this code but I am not able to aggregate in month

```
df %>% group_by(DATE) %>%
  count(values)
```

from this, I am getting the frequency for daily

```
group_by(month = month(date)) %>% count(values)
```

when I was trying this code to aggregate date in month then i was getting following error

```
    (Error in as.POSIXlt.character(as.character(x), ...) : 

  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format)
```

I want my output like this

```
date  values  freq
11/18  a       1
11/18  b       1
12/18  a       6
12/18  b       5
12/18  c       6
```

and the same for other months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the month from `date` and then use `count`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(month = format(as.Date(date, "%m/%d/%y"), "%m/%y")) %>%
  count(month, values)

#   month values     n
#   <chr> <fct>  <int>
# 1 01/19 a          2
# 2 01/19 b          1
# 3 01/19 c          2
# 4 01/19 d          4
# 5 02/19 a          2
# 6 02/19 b          1
# 7 03/19 c          1
# 8 03/19 d          1
# 9 05/19 a          1
#10 05/19 c          1
#11 05/19 d          2
#12 11/18 a          1
#13 11/18 b          1
#14 12/18 a          6
#15 12/18 b          5
#16 12/18 c          3
```

Or keeping completely in base R, we can use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(date~month+values, 
     transform(df, month = format(as.Date(date, "%m/%d/%y"), "%m/%y")), length)
```

Comment: @xyz Hi...I would suggest you to ask a new question instead of updating the original post. It invalidates the current answers which are not helpful for future readers. You can read more about this at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296489/when-is-it-ok-to-extend-a-question-with-another-question-after-initial-answers and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254521/editing-question-for-new-answer

Comment: but I have edited the question so the answer is not going to match with the question

Comment: you can roll back to the previous edit. I can do it for you if you are facing difficulties in doing so.

Comment: can you do that for me? and I have asked another question related to this can you check that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57746602/dividing-column-values-in-range-and-aggregate-date-by-month-to-count-frequency-o

Answer (score 1):

We can use `base R` with `table`

```
with(df1, as.data.frame(table(format(as.Date(date, "%m/%d/%y"), "%m/%y"), values)))
```

Advantage is that it would also provide the information about the combinations that are absent with 'Freq' as 0